# Isomorphism between $D_{24}$ and $S_3\times\mathbb Z_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> I'm trying to disprove that $D_{24}$ is isomorphic to $S_3\times\mathbb Z_4$ without explicitly using semi direct products, but I'm stuck.

Both are non-abelian, right? And I can't find an element of a certain order that one has but the other one lacks.

How do I show that they can't be isomorphic?

Comment: Have you tried using generators ?

Comment: @SoumikGhosh I've tried thinking of the possible mappings from the generators of $D_{24}$ but could't find anything useful. How would you do it this way?

Comment: Have you learned about the center of a group yet?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes. The center of $D_{28}$ is of order 2 and the center of the other group is trivial, right? And I've proven that isomorphic groups must have isomorphic centers. So this will do it.

Comment: The center of the other group is not trivial, but it's not of order $2$ either.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Haha right I just realized that (I was thinking just of $S_3$.) But yes, the other group's will be of order 4, I believe, which will do it.

Comment: Yep, there you go!  Feel free to write up your own answer.

Comment: Ha. I put this question on an exam recently. One way to go is to see that the first group has more elements of order 2 than the second group has.

Answer (score 3):

In $D_{24}$ we have an element of order $2$, $s$ and an element of order $12$, $r$ satisfying $srs=r^{-1}$. The elements of order $12$ in $S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ all look like $x=((123),1)$, i.e. the product of an element of order $3$ and one of order $4$. Given any $(g,h)\in S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_4$, because $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is abelian, 
$$(g,h)x(g^{-1},h^{-1})=(g(123)g^{-1},1)$$ which is not the inverse of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $Z(D_{24})=\{1, r^6\}$, since $n$ is even. Further, we have $Z(S_3\times\mathbb Z_4)=\{1, (1, x), (1, x^2), (1, x^3)\}$. Since the centers of isomorphic groups must be isomorphic themselves, we have that the two original groups cannot be isomorphic, as their centers have different orders.